# join a image in mi view in django

Tags: python, django

Actually the original image is save on my downloads but I need the image to be stored in the database, not in my downloads, with the "nombre" of my model "programas"

My model:

```
class programas(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    nombre = models.CharField('Nombres',max_length=50, blank= True)
    horas = models.CharField('Horas',max_length=50, blank= True)
    creditos = models.CharField('Creditos',max_length=50, blank= True)
    imagen = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True)
```

My view:

```
def registroPrograma(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProgramaForms(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():

            programas = form.save(commit=False)
            programas.creditos= request.user
            imagen = qrcode.make('Hola Iver!')
            img = Image.open(programas.imagen)
            img = img.resize((2500, 2500), Image.ANTIALIAS)
            img = img.convert('JPG')
            img.paste(imagen, (0, 0))
            x = img.save("/Downloads/hola.jpg")
            programas.imagen = img.paste(imagen, (0, 0))
            form.save()
        return redirect('principio')
    else:
        form = ProgramaForms()
    return render(request,'registrar_programa.html', {'form':form})
```

Comment: Storing images in a database is usually considered an anitpattern - if you don't understand why by now, just wait until you have a couple terabytes of images in your db...

Answer (score 0):

First of all, This should be the code you'll remember when you go professional with django, Joining images on views will add a lot of waiting time if the form is valid because you're working with files there, *NEVER* do this, Working with files should be off the main thread or process, That's why [Celery](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/django/first-steps-with-django.html) exists.

Secondly, Storing files in the database is a bad performance practice, Howevere there's a `BinaryField` which the document says about it in [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#binaryfield)..

> Although you might think about storing files in the database, consider that it is bad design in 99% of the cases. This field is not a replacement for proper static files handling.

Please re-condsider revamping how your app works instead, This will ensure better scalability and maintainability for it.